# Google Big Query- Public Dataset "Cymbal: Google Cloud's demo brand" not availabe

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset

I tried to locate the public dataset "Cymbal: Google Cloud's demo brand", but it does not seem to be available to me at the moment. Can anybody open this dataset?

https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/cymbal/cymbal

Thanks and regards
Sven

Answer (score 0):

"Cymbal: Google Cloud's demo brand" dataset is available for me. But if I click view dataset, it's not opening, and it redirects me to the same page. Maybe you can try it after sometime, it will work, or you can raise this in public issue [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659).