# Google BigQuery Cymbal Group data sets

Tags: google-bigquery

This is not so much a programming question as it is a public data set question. Please let me know if there is a more appropriate venue to ask this.

I have been trying to find out more information about this data set:
https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/cymbal/cymbal

> **About Cymbal: Google Cloud's demo brand**
>
> Cymbal Group
>
> Synthetic datasets across industries showcasing Google Cloud.
>
> ​ I can not see it when I use the Explorer to browse
> bigquery-public-data. I can see the cymbal_investments dataset but not
> the one described above.
>
> I am especially interested in the Retail Subsidiaries data such as:
>
> Cymbal Superstore — An American superstore and grocer with a
> multinational presence.
>
> Cymbal Shops — An American retail chain selling homewares,
> electronics, and clothing.
>
> Cymbal Direct — An online direct-to-consumer Chicago-Based footwear
> and apparel retailer.

Please let me know if you can point me to the right dataset.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Seems this has been an issue for a while... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499423/google-big-query-public-dataset-cymbal-google-clouds-demo-brand-not-availab

Comment: I created a public issue for this. See https://issuetracker.google.com/215476205. You can star the public issue tracker feature requests. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it.

Comment: Thanks - I starred it.  Does anyone know any actual human beings at Google who we could try to contact?